# Geometrical Transformation

Tags: math, geometry, transformation

I goggled for some hours but haven't found a suitable ans to solve the problem. need some help.

Qs. 1.
I have Rectangle A of Width="150" Height="423", 
Now I want to place a Rectangle B of Width="370" Height="700" inside A.
How can I calculate the size of B without changing its aspect ratio, if I want to place it inside A.

Qs. 2.
Rectangle A of Width="150" Height="423", Holding Rectangle B of Width="370" Height="700" 
Now I need to the view of Width="150" Height="150", so I have to scale the Rectangle A so B gives a view of Width="150" Height="150". How can I calculate the scaleX, scaleY.

And realy thanks for the help.

Comment: "accepted ratio"? maybe _aspect ratio_?

Comment: Qs2 is unclear. Could you show a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1:
Let's rectangle A dimensions are Wa, Ha, and rectangle B dimensions are Wb, Hb.
Rectangle B will fit vertically if ratio of A and B heights less than ratio of A and B widths, and will fit horizontally otherwise:

```
Coeff = Min(Wa/Wb, Ha/Hb)
Wbnew = Wb * Coeff
Hbnew = Hb * Coeff
```

Comment: Please supplement your answer with an explanation as well.

Comment: thank u MBo, I already got the ans of Q2 from Q1. Thanks again.